# Python. Использование dataclass как type annotation/hinting

Tags: python

Я хотел использовать дата классы для указания типов, но они с этим не помогают.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class PersonDS:
    name: str
    age: int
    lang: str = 'eng'


def greet(name: PersonDS.name):
    print(f'Hello {name}')
    return name / 2  # Нет подсветки синтаксиса в Pycharm


foo = greet(name=5)  # Нет подсветки синтаксиса в Pycharm
```

Иногда я действительно создаю `person`, но чаще использую как `type hinting`.

Напрямую в ф-ях задавать тип не хочу, потому что он может поменяться

Можно ли все-же использовать `dataclass` для `type hinting`, и что вообще можно сделать в такой ситуации?

Comment: Зачем использовать dataclass для type hinting? Если вы хотите задать типу str своё имя, то просто возьмите и создайте соответствующую переменную `PersonName = str` и потом используйте её в аннотациях `name: PersonName`

Comment: На мой взгляд использование датаклассов было бы лаконично.
Хочется какую-то структуру, вроде класса создать для типов 1-го объекта.

Comment: Вы пытаетесь использовать датаклассы не по назначению, поэтому это не лаконичность, а попытка сломать мозг тем, кто будет читать ваш код в будущем. Впрочем, я к сожалению не знаю, можно ли как-то «официально» красиво группировать типы

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае, поведение является нормальным, type hinting не применяет аннотацию типов

> Note The Python runtime does not enforce function and variable type annotations. They can be used by third party tools such as type checkers, IDEs, linters, etc.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

первая ссылка в гугл даст понимание больше https://devpractice.ru/python-lesson-18-annotations/#p4

для проверки типов необходимо использовать линтеры типа mypy

Comment: Да это понятно, но как раз Pycharm ничего не подсвечивает. Об этом говорит комментарий в примере кода.

Comment: можно написать так `def greet(name: type(PersonDS.name)):`